# Create API for registering user on wordpress site with 3rd party site

Tags: plugins, api

My site needs to integrate with a 3rd party CRM software, which will live on its own sub-domain, hosted by the CRM company.

1) www.example.com - Main Site
2) testsite.example.com - CRM Hosted on the subdomain

I need to provide the 3rd party developers with an endpoint that they can use to make API calls (to my wordpress site) in order to allow my 3rd party site's to register a user on my wordpress site.

The CRM site will be the one handling all the payment and Subscription.
so if a user makes registration a subscription on the CRM site.
the user needs to be addedd in the wordpress website using the API call and the user role set to be Member bcoz the Main site is an educational website where we host educational videos.

The CRM website is a Affiliate program website.

I'm not sure where to start, but my sense is that this has been figured out by people smarter than me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use the REST API for that.  check out the docs for more details.  https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user

Answer (score 0):

Newer Versions of Wordpress include a pretty complete REST API.
You can use the [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) to find information how to use it.

You can find information about how to create a user on this page: [Creating A User](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user)